# Elastic - Bulk upload: index x update

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, bulk

I have 2 distinguished bulk uploads to perform, and the sequence that each will happen is completely unpredictable
In one load I would have the fields: `SERVER_NAME`, `OS`, and `PROD_1_VERSION`
In the other one, I would have the fields: `SERVER_NAME`, `OS`, and `PROD_2_VERSION`

My files look like this:

```
{"index":{"_index" : "myindex", "_id" : "MY_SERVER_1" }}
{"SERVER_NAME":"MY_SERVER_1","OS":"Ubuntu","PROD_1_VERSION":"1.0.0.5" }
{"index":{"_index" : "myindex", "_id" : "MY_SERVER_2" }}
{"SERVER_NAME":"MY_SERVER_2","OS":"Windows10","PROD_1_VERSION":"2.0.0.0" }
{"index":{"_index" : "myindex", "_id" : "MY_SERVER_3" }}
{"SERVER_NAME":"MY_SERVER_3","OS":"Fedora","PROD_1_VERSION":"2.5.0.1" }
```

and:

```
{"index":{"_index" : "myindex", "_id" : "MY_SERVER_1" }}   
{"SERVER_NAME":"MY_SERVER_1","OS":"Ubuntu","PROD_2_VERSION":"6.0.0.5" } 
{"index":{"_index" : "myindex", "_id" : "MY_SERVER_2" }}
{"SERVER_NAME":"MY_SERVER_2","OS":"Windows10","PROD_2_VERSION":"7.0.0.0" } 
{"index":{"_index" : "myindex", "_id" : "MY_SERVER_3" }}
{"SERVER_NAME":"MY_SERVER_3","OS":"Fedora","PROD_2_VERSION":"8.5.0.1" }
```

- If I do the loads in the given sequence, and using `"index"` the property `"PROD_2_VERSION"` will be added, but `"PROD_1_VERSION"` will be lost
- If I modify it, and use `"update"` rather then `"index"` (including `{ "doc" : ... }` before the properties ), the first load fails, as it tries to update something that does not exist yet
- If the first load has `"index"` and the second has `"update"` it works, however, as mentioned, the sequence that each will happen can't be controlled.

Is there a way to make it works like this:

```
if record exit, 
   use behave like 'index'
else
   behave like 'update'
```

???

Comment: Are you sure about your pseudo code? I read it like this: if the record already exists, index the data (why?), otherwise **if it doesn't exist**, update it (how can you update something that doesn't exist)...

Comment: What I meant was almost the opposite ... 
If both I use "index" on both loads, when the second one runs, to add some fields (in this case "PROD_2_VERSION") the fields that were added on the first load will be lost. 
If both I use "update" on both loads, the first one will fail, because there is no record to update.
So I would need to have "index" in the 1st, and "update" in the 2nd ... but I can't predict which one will run first.
As replied by @Jaycreation, the usage of "doc_as_upsert" in an "update" solves the issue!

Comment: That's what I would have suggested if the pseudo code was correct in the first place ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to totally understand your use case. But to do an "upsert" (insert or update) in a bulk into elastic search you must add

```
"doc_as_upsert" : true
```

After your doc part.

Here is the example of the [official elasticsearch's documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-update):

```
{ "update" : {"_id" : "2", "_index" : "index1", "retry_on_conflict" : 3} }
{ "doc" : {"field" : "value"}, "doc_as_upsert" : true }
```

Comment: "doc_as_upsert" was exactly what I was missing, thanks a lot @Jaycreation !!! I am completely new to Elastic, and the "how-to" doc which I got didn't have that covered!

Comment: The learning curve is quite long with elastic. So don't worry you will find a lot and a lot of details like this. If you need to speed up your progression you can contact me via the website in my profile